# How do you log HTTP requests with xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Trying to debug API calls but it I am not sure how to log all the http requests I make.

I'd like to see things all the headers and params outgoing and incoming.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your NSURLResponse objects to NSHTTPURLResponses, then you can do:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
// ...
NSLog(@"My response headers: %@", [response allHeaderFields]);
NSLog(@"My response code: %d (%@), response.statusCode, [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedDescriptionForStatusCode:response.statusCode]);
```

NSURLRequests are already fairly transparent...

Comment: I am unable to see query string params because I am not setting the params in the request body.